# IMPORTHTML data is sporadically changing to incorrect format

Tags: google-sheets-query, importhtml, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm hoping you can help me with my problem  using `importhtml` with Google Sheets.  It is a problem similar to [Trying to use Google Sheets importHTML() to import a table. It forces content to a date format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100415/trying-to-use-google-sheets-importhtml-to-import-a-table-it-forces-content-to/100473#100473)

I am using `importhtml` and `query` together to get data that includes duration data that can be in either XX:XX or XX:XX:XX.  The data is not always HH:MM:SS format.  Sometimes it's MM:SS:00 Sometimes it's MM:SS, and others are HH:MM:SS.

If I use `importthtml` and view the data while the the column is set to Automatic formatting, view of data is correct.
However if I use query, in some cases the data changes to something weird, especially if the leading value is `24`.  `24` gets translated into `00`.  I guess it's getting confused with a time value.  I would like either data to remain exactly as it comes from the URL, but it seems Google Sheets tries to format it.
I've tried many different workarounds to no avail.

The table lookup with correct time values is:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/profile.aspx?athleteid=800922&viewby=date","table",18)
```

But using `query` in conjunction with `importhtml` I get different values for only some of the results.

```
=query(IMPORTHTML("http://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/profile.aspx?athleteid=800922&viewby=date","table",18),"select Col1, Col2")
```

I hope that there is some way to get the data to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

*Possibly* try a different approach. Don't use query but instead, in A1 and copied across to B1:

```
=index(IMPORTHTML("http://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/profile.aspx?athleteid=800922&viewby=date","table",18),,column())
```

Then either format ColumnB as Duration (and accept some extra zeros) or also use the plain IMPORTHTML as the source to copy format only from its relevant column into ColumnB and then delete the 'plain' formula.