# IMPORTHTML incorrectly formats colon separated data as Time

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I have sport data that I imported from a website [link](https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/japan/japan-cup/standings/?table=table&table_sub=&ts=begojFEk&dcheck=0) into google sheet using importhtml() function

| # | Team | MP | W | WO | LO | L | G | Pts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Red Eagles Hokkaido | 26 | 20 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 110:55 | 64 |
| 2. | Nikko Ice Bucks | 24 | 15 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 106:65 | 48 |
| 3. | Tohoku Free Blades | 28 | 11 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 98:82 | 44 |
| 4. | East Hokkaido Cranes | 26 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 12 | 86:85 | 34 |
| 5. | Yokohama Grits | 28 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 23 | 44:157 | 8 |

There is a particular column named G in which, two data are combined together in each cells and partitioned with colon `:` and when the data is imported into the google sheet, it formats G column as date/time.

Examples given:

1. For the first cell of colum G,  which has 110:55 from the website,  it was imported as 110:55:00. That is in hh:mm:ss format.
2. For the second cell which has 106:65 on the site,  it was imported as 107:05:00 in hh:mm:ss.  The 65 in the data from website was assumed to be 65min,  then it was counted as an hour and was added to initial 106 to make it 107.

[image: attached is the pic of the table]

Attached is the pic of how the table looks when imported to google sheet [image: Attached sheet]

How can I work around it?

Similar question was answered in this thread [Trying to use Google Sheets importHTML() to import a table. It forces content to a date format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100415/trying-to-use-google-sheets-importhtml-to-import-a-table-it-forces-content-to)
But they are different.  The mentioned thread works on date format while mine is on time format.  Date format doesn't chanhe after 60 seconds or 60 minutes like a time format.

The formula used in the thread mentioned above has been tried but didn't work.
you may as well tried using it incase I missed something.
[image: I got this] Got this with Aurrielle Perlmann formula with the modification below `={ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTHTML("https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/japan/japan-cup/standings/?table=table&table_sub=&ts=begojFEk&dcheck=0","table",1), 100, 7), ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TEXT(IMPORTHTML("https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/japan/japan-cup/standings/?table=table&table_sub=&ts=begojFEk&dcheck=0","table",1), "hh:mm:ss"), "select Col8"), "(\d:\d\d)(:\d\d)", "$1"))}`  I was unable to work around Ruben's formula

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# URL of the API
url = "https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/japan/japan-cup/standings/?table=table&table_sub=&ts=begojFEk&dcheck=0"

# Send a GET request to the API
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Assuming the API returns JSON data, which needs to be verified
    data = response.json()

    # Convert data to a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Ensure column 'G' is treated as integer
    df['G'] = df['G'].astype(int)

    # Export to Excel
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: I am working on google sheet. I used Importhtml() and also it is not necessary an api, a website per say.  Pls I have made adjustments to the question for easy understanding sir.